# CryptoJS not decrypting non-Latin characters faithfully

Tags: javascript, cryptojs, latin1

I am trying to use CryptoJS AES, like so:

```
var msg = "café";
var key = "something";
var c = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key).toString();
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(c, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);
```

Unfortunately this returns `cafÃ©`, not `café`. Clearly Latin1 is not the right encoding to use, but I can't find a better one. Is there a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the format 
The proper way is using  `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8`

So, Please try:

`CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(c, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);`

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd tried that already and it had failed - but I had accidentally used `utf8` not `Utf8`.

Answer (score 2):

https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Input

> The hash algorithms accept either strings or instances of CryptoJS.lib.WordArray [...] an array of 32-bit words. When you pass a string, it's ***automatically converted to a WordArray encoded as UTF-8***.

So, when you pass a string (and don't use CryptoJS.enc.* to generate a `WordArray`) it automatically converts the string (`message`) to a utf8 `WordArray`.

See here for sample roundtrip encrypt/decrypt:
https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Cipher_Output

Here's a jsfiddle to play with CryptoJS
https://jsfiddle.net/8qbf4746/4/

```
var message = "café";
var key = "something";

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key);
//equivalent to CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message), key);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);

$('#1').text("Encrypted: "+encrypted);
$('#2').text("Decrypted: "+decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

To emphasize my point here is the same thing using Latin1 encoding:
https://jsfiddle.net/3a8tf48f/2/

```
var message = "café";
var key = "something";

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(message), key);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);

$('#1').text("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
$('#2').text("Decrypted: " + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1));
```

On a side note, the API would probably be better if it only accepted `WordArray` and didn't overload the toString method (which is just a convenience interface to CryptoJS.enc.*.stringify).  The string conversion magic is a little misleading.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to decrypt your data as a Latin1 string, even though your input string is not in Latin1. The encoding used by CryptoJS internally is not the same as the encoding you use to write the input file.

You need to specify the same encoding both when encrypting (for the string -> byte array conversion) and when decrypting (for the byte array -> string conversion).

Comment: That's what the question is asking. Simply repeating the facts stated in the question doesn't make it an answer.

Comment: The question says nothing about specifying encoding explicitely when encrypting, which is exactly what I am suggesting. And I believe this is a better approach than just assuming that the CryptoJS default will always be UTF-8, and it also makes your code easier to understand.

Comment: Ok, that little bit wasn't in the question, but you're not saying which encoding should be used (the fact that another answer mentioned). It's a perfectly fine answer to say that the default encoding might change in the future, but you should also say which encoding is currently used. I've always found the best way to know these things is to look into the source code. (I'll gladly remove my downvote if you edit your answer.)